# Stripe Integration Swift Cloud Functions

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe connect into my ios app but I'm having some difficulties. I used cloud functions and did payment intent successfully. Now I'm trying to create an account for my sellers also using cloud functions. This is what i did so far but i don't know how to integrate it into my app. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the docs I'm following https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

Cloud function code

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  async function run() {

    const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      account: 'Acc',
      refresh_url: 'https://example.com/reauth',
      return_url: 'https://example.com/return',
      type: 'account_onboarding',
    });

  };
```

Swift Code

```
class StripeTestViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    let BackendAPIBaseURL: String = "NoCodeAPI" // Set to the URL of your backend server

  

        // ...

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let connectWithStripeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
            connectWithStripeButton.setTitle("Connect with Stripe", for: .normal)
            connectWithStripeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectConnectWithStripe), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(connectWithStripeButton)

            // ...
        }

        @objc
        func didSelectConnectWithStripe() {
            if let url = URL(string: BackendAPIBaseURL)?.appendingPathComponent("onboard-user") {
              var request = URLRequest(url: url)
              request.httpMethod = "POST"
              let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                  guard let data = data,
                      let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                      let accountURLString = json["url"] as? String,
                      let accountURL = URL(string: accountURLString) else {
                       return             }

                  let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: accountURL)
                  safariViewController.delegate = self

                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.present(safariViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                  }
              }
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Which specific part doesn't work for you and which part you don't get? At a first glance your backend function (cloud function code) doesn't seem to return a response yet. You would want to return a JSON with `url` property, so your Swift code can take it and open in Safari `let accountURLString = json["url"] as? String`

Comment: Where would I get the url as I'm using firebase as my database.